# How virtual inheritance is implemented in memory by c++ compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am baffled by the VIRTUAL keyword. I am trying to find how does compiler implement this in memory. 
ok so let me explain with examples. I am using Microsoft Visual studio 2010 as implementation of virtual depends on compiler.

here is the first code

```
#include<iostream>
class one
{
    int _a;
public:
    virtual ~one(){}
};
class two:public one
{
    int _a;
public:
    virtual ~two(){}
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout<<"sizeof two="<<sizeof(two)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

o/p is 12 bytes, because of _*vptr*_two,one::_a and two::_a

here is another example code

```
#include<iostream>
class one
{
    int _a;
public:
    virtual ~one(){}
};
class two
{
    int _a;
public:
    virtual ~two(){}
};
class three:virtual public one,virtual public two
{
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout<<"sizeof three="<<sizeof(three)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

in this case o/p is 20 bytes :O, how come?? Please explain!! According to me it should be 16 bytes.
__vptr_three(pointer to vtable), _vptr1_three(pointer to virtual base class table), one::_a and two::_a. And why virtual base class table is maintained ?

Comment: Note: your example of virtual base class is... strange. In theory virtual inheritance is used to solve the *Diamond Problem*: D inherits from C and B and both C and B inherit from A. You have no diamond, so virtual inheritance is useless in your case.

Comment: @MatthieuM. your point is relevant matt but i am not trying to implement anything i am just learning :) and when you learn you should learn all aspects !!!

Answer (score 8):

This [pdf](http://www.openrce.org/articles/files/jangrayhood.pdf) contains everything that you need to understand about, how virtual inheritance is implemented in VC++, by the writer of the compiler.

Below is the disassembly for the constructor of `class three`,

```
00A516BD  cmp         dword ptr [ebp+8],0 
00A516C1  je          three::three+60h (0A516F0h) 
00A516C3  mov         eax,dword ptr [this] 
00A516C6  mov         dword ptr [eax],offset three::`vbtable' (0A57828h) => 4 Bytes
00A516CC  mov         ecx,dword ptr [this] 
00A516CF  add         ecx,8 
00A516D2  call        one::one (0A51253h) 
00A516D7  or          dword ptr [ebp-0D4h],1 
00A516DE  mov         ecx,dword ptr [this] 
00A516E1  add         ecx,10h 
00A516E4  call        two::two (0A512BCh) 
00A516E9  or          dword ptr [ebp-0D4h],2 
00A516F0  mov         eax,dword ptr [this] 
00A516F3  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax] 
00A516F5  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+4] 
00A516F8  mov         eax,dword ptr [this] 
00A516FB  mov         dword ptr [eax+edx],offset three::`vftable' (0A57820h)  => 4 Bytes
00A51702  mov         eax,dword ptr [this] 
00A51705  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax] 
00A51707  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+8] 
00A5170A  mov         eax,dword ptr [this] 
00A5170D  mov         dword ptr [eax+edx],offset three::`vftable' (0A57814h)   => 4 Bytes
00A51714  mov         eax,dword ptr [this] 
00A51717  pop         edi  
00A51718  pop         esi  
00A51719  pop         ebx  
00A5171A  add         esp,0D8h
```

As you can see above, 
The virtual base table pointer takes 4 bytes, (vbtable)
2 virtual function table pointer takes 4 * 2 = 8 bytes, (vftable)
The member `one::_a` takes 4 bytes
The member `two::_a` takes 4 bytes

Hence in all 20 bytes.
The reason for 2 virtual function table pointers is given in the pdf (page 17) as follows,

"In Visual C++, to avoid costly conversions to the virtual base P when fetching a vftable entry, new virtual functions of T, receive entries in a new vftable, requiring a new vfptr, introduced at the top of T."

Comment: I think, you should add some paragraphs from the pdf to the answer in case if this pdf will be removed.

Comment: Indeed, link-only answers are frowned upon because they tend to link-rot. It is fine, and actually encouraged, to provide *references* to supplement your answers; however the meat of the answer should be immediately accessible on Stack Overflow (if only in broad strokes). It would also be helpful if you explained why 20...

Comment: @51k good to know that the pdf answers it,hang on i am on page 11 :) !!

Comment: "As you can see above" -- this should read "As you can clearly see above"

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely implementation-specific, and a compiler is at liberty to organise things any way it likes (and make the resulting classes any size it likes) providing it all works.

From the look of things, I assume that class `three` contains three hidden pointers (each 4 bytes on your system): one "virtual base pointer", containing the addresses of the virtual bases within `three`, one virtual function pointer containing the addresses of the virtual functions in `one`, and a second virtual function pointer containing the addresses of the virtual functions in `two`.

So that's 3 * 4 bytes for the pointers, plus 2 * 4 bytes for the two `int` members of the base classes, giving a total of 20 bytes.

Of course, if you were to compile this code on a 64-bit machine (with 8 byte pointers), then you'd get something different: at least 32 bytes, but possibly more if the compiler decided it needed to pad the `int` members.

Comment: This is what i suspected too, but why two virtual function pointers ??